# Can I connect browser right-click with Power Automate script?

Tags: browser, power-automate-desktop

Suppose I right-click on an image or a link (or some other element) in the browser. How can I arrange to have a script invoked afterwards that receives data about the clicked element?

Thanks for any discussion.

Comment: Did you mean Power Automate Desktop?

Comment: @Skin: Yes! Thanks, didn't think to mention that.

Comment: You can't invoke a script persay, it's really not that clever.  You can't do it from a click but you can tell it that you want to specifically look for that element in a PAD script.  What's your use case, maybe that will help me understand more.

Comment: @Skin: Given what you've written, it's probably impossible. But here's a use case anyway. Suppose I'm on page https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/b00vxz48 and I would like to right-click on one of the images displayed under the heading 'Coming Up Next' and have Power Automate (somehow) collect the URL associated with this image and do something nice with it. Is there a way? Thanks for staying with me so far.